# Editing multiple elements with one function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm designing an HTML page that uses javascript. I'm trying to get multiple parts of the page to display user-selected units. I have one input field that says:

```
    Length Units: <input id="lengthunits" size="7" onblur="updateunits();"></input>
```

Then I have multiple places in the page where I want the units displayed. For example, I might have the field:

```
    Dimension 1 (<span id="dim1"></span>): <input id="dimension1"></input>
```

Then in the updateunits function I have:

```
    function updateunits() {
    document.getElementById("dim1").innerHTML=document.getElementById("lengthunits").value;
    }
```

This works fine, but I have to add a line of code to the function, and use a separate id, for anywhere in the page where I want the length units displayed.
I was wondering if there's an easier/better way of doing this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could change the ids to classes then use getElementsByClassName. This would ease the pain of creating ids for each element. You could also use the data-* attribute ( date-dimension=1) on each element then use querySelectorAll to find the correct elements. Either way, both methods return an array in which you just need to iterate over to set the new values.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead of id's:

```
<input id="lengthunits" size="7" onblur="updateunits();"></input>
<span class="dim"></span>
<span class="dim"></span>
<span class="dim"></span>
```

Fetch them using `getElementsByClassname`, loop over them and do your thing:

```
function updateunits() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("dim");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].innerHTML = document.getElementById("lengthunits").value;
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Guess I'll have to look into getElementsByClassName. Thanks!

Comment: So getElementsByClassName essentially creates an array (node list?), changing the values of which will also change the values of the original elements? Is it basically just an array of pointers to the original elements?

Comment: Yup, sort of, not a nodelist. It returns a HTMLcollection (The HTMLCollection interface represents a generic collection (array-like object) of elements) of all the elements you've given that class. Then you can loop over them and change them. See: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options. I'll assume you're not interested in anything like jQuery since you're not using it above.

So plain JS solutions

### Use a Class

Give each element that should be updated a class, such as "updateable"

```
function updateUnits() {
    var val = document.getElementById("lengthunits").value;
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("updateable");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        elements[i].innerHTML = document.getElementById("lengthunits").value;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOEjeb?editors=101

### Global Variable

This method keeps your html clean, but i'd say it's a bit harder to maintain.

```
function updateUnits() {
    elements = [document.getElementById("id1"), document.getElementById("id2")]
    var val = document.getElementById("lengthunits").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        elements[i].innerHTML = document.getElementById("lengthunits").value;
}
```

CodePen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyPgKz

It's all the same really, it's just about how you want to designate your entities to update. Once you have them in an array, the code's very simple.